# How to present error message if one of the JSON items is not returned. Just simply want to say something like "We could not find your order number"

Tags: javascript, html, json

How do I present an error message if one of the JSON items is not returned? Just simply want to say something like "We could not find your order number". I feel dumb asking something that might be so simple.

If you can view the *order.js* file, you will see a couple of ordernumbers and section numbers. Ideally, the user should know their order number from an email they already own. The user is interested in finding out what section their order is in. To find out, they need to type in their Order Number.

```js
/* JSON data that is inputted manually */ 

let data = [   
        {
            "OrderNumber": "8306",
            "Section": "120"
        },
     
        {
            "OrderNumber": "8373",
            "Section": "120"
        },
        {
            "OrderNumber": "8932",
            "Section": "120"
        }
]
/* Create the append to show the section number after the user inputs thier order number. User would know order number from email confirmation that they already own */ 
function searchValue() {

  let srchString = ''
  var searchField = $('#search').val().trim();
  let srchVal = data.filter(val => val.OrderNumber.includes(searchField))
  
  srchVal.forEach((item) => {
  srchString += `<li>Your number is ${item.Section}</li>`

  })
    {
        $('#resultDiv').empty().append(srchString);
       
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.btn-success {
    background: #004c54 !important;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#resultDiv {
    margin-top: 20%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;

}

#searchresult {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

header.masthead {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #004c54;

    padding-top: 6rem;
    padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

header.masthead .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #212529;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

header.masthead h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    header.masthead {
        padding-top: 2rem;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    header.masthead h1 {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
}

.showcase .showcase-text {
    padding: 3rem;
}

.showcase .showcase-img {
    min-height: 30rem;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .showcase .showcase-text {
        padding: 7rem;
    }
}

.features-icons {
    padding-top: 7rem;
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
}

.features-icons .features-icons-item {
    max-width: 27rem;
}

.features-icons .features-icons-item .features-icons-icon {
    height: 7rem;
}

.features-icons .features-icons-item .features-icons-icon i {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
}

.features-icons .features-icons-item:hover .features-icons-icon i {
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.testimonials {
    padding-top: 7rem;
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
}

.testimonials .testimonial-item {
    max-width: 18rem;
}

.testimonials .testimonial-item img {
    max-width: 12rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px #adb5bd;
}

.call-to-action {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #343a40;
    background: url("../img/bg-masthead.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.call-to-action .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #212529;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

footer.footer {
    padding-top: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Find My Cutout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Masthead containing HEading -->
    <header class="masthead text-white text-center">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
                    <h1 class="mb-5">Test JSON</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mx-auto">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>


    <section class="features-icons bg-light text-center">
        <div id="ancestor">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-5 mb-lg-0 mb-lg-3">

                            <input type="text" id='search' name="contacts" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter your order number" maxlength="4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success" value='Search' onclick='searchValue()' id="submit" disabled>Search Order ID</button>
                            <div id='resultDiv'></div>



                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    

    <script src="order.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Forces user to enter in order # at min and max of 4 characters --->
    <script>
        $('#ancestor input').on('keyup', function() {

            var contacts = $('input[name=contacts]').val();

            $('#submit').prop('disabled', !(contacts.length >= 4));
        });
    </script>


    <!-- Allows enter button on keyboard to submit --->
    <script>
        var input = document.getElementById("search");
        input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById("submit").click();
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there, just check for `srchString` variable's length. If it's zero append the custom message saying *"We could not find your order number"* else show the search result.

```js
let data = [{
    "OrderNumber": "8306",
    "Section": "120"
  },

  {
    "OrderNumber": "8373",
    "Section": "120"
  },
  {
    "OrderNumber": "8932",
    "Section": "120"
  }
]
/* Create the append to show the section number after the user inputs thier order number. User would know order number from email confirmation that they already own */
function searchValue() {

  let srchString = ''
  var searchField = $('#search').val().trim();
  let srchVal = data.filter(val => val.OrderNumber.includes(searchField))

  srchVal.forEach((item) => {
    srchString += `<li>Your number is ${item.Section}</li>`

  })
  if (srchString.length > 0) {
    $('#resultDiv').empty().append(srchString);
  } else {
    $('#resultDiv').empty().append('<li>We could not find your order number</li>');
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn-success {
  background: #004c54 !important;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#resultDiv {
  margin-top: 20%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#searchresult {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Find My Cutout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Masthead containing HEading -->
  <header class="masthead text-white text-center">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="mb-5">Test JSON</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mx-auto">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


  <section class="features-icons bg-light text-center">
    <div id="ancestor">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="features-icons-item mx-auto mb-5 mb-lg-0 mb-lg-3">

              <input type="text" id='search' name="contacts" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter your order number" maxlength="4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success" value='Search' onclick='searchValue()' id="submit" disabled>Search Order ID</button>
              <div id='resultDiv'></div>



            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <script src="order.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Forces user to enter in order # at min and max of 4 characters --->
  <script>
    $('#ancestor input').on('keyup', function() {

      var contacts = $('input[name=contacts]').val();

      $('#submit').prop('disabled', !(contacts.length >= 4));
    });
  </script>


  <!-- Allows enter button on keyboard to submit --->
  <script>
    var input = document.getElementById("search");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("submit").click();
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Sandeep Joshi.  I really appreciate the quick response and help.

Comment: glad that it helped. please mark the answer accepted and upvote. this helps u as well as me :)